# jQuery events are not getting loaded in document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written some `click` events on `document.ready()`. Some of them are working as expected. But few of them are not loading unless i put them inside `setTimeout()`.

It is not working

```
$('.clsName').click(function(){ //code here   });
```

But, this one will work

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.clsName').click(function(){ //code here});
}.2000);
```

Comment: @prasad why would that help over `document.ready`?

Comment: if it work also, I wanna know why its happening. Some of them are loading some need `setTimeout()`

Comment: Are you adding some `.clsName` elements to the DOM after the page has loaded? If so you need to use a delegated event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try this

```
$(document).on('click','.clsName',function(){ //code here   });
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.